# Component ace:dialog doesn't work

Tags: jsf, icefaces, jsf-2.3

I'm using icefaces 4.2 and jsf 2.3. I'm trying to get dialog window on client side. My code:

```
<ace:dialog modal="true" clientOnly="true" autoCentre="false">
<div class="md-dialog">
<f:facet name="header">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{sC.isFileUpl==null}">
        <div class="md-dialog-header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{sC.mCompat.component.title}"/>
                    <h:commandLink partialSubmit="true"
                                     title="#{res['web_close]}"
                                     actionListener="#{sC.modComponent.closePopup}"
                                     styleClass="dialogButton" style="border: none;">
                        <ace:ajax/>
                        <img border="0" alt="#{res['web_close']}"
                             src="#{sC.style.closeIcon}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
        </div>
    </ui:fragment>

    <ui:fragment rendered="#{sC.isFileUpl!=null}">
      <div class="mod-dialog-2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{sC.file.title}"/>

                    <h:commandLink partialSubmit="true"
                                     title="#{res['web_close']}"
                                     actionListener="#{sC.file.cancel}"
                                     styleClass="dialogButton"
                                     style="border: none;">
                        <ace:ajax/>
                        <img border="0" alt="#{res['web_close']}"
                             src="#{sC.style.closeIcon}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
        </div>
    </ui:fragment>
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="body">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{sC.isFileUpl==null}">
    <div class="#{sC.modComponent.component.fClass}">
        <ui:include src="#{sC.modComponent.component.facelet}">
            <ui:param name="#{sC.modComponent.component.paramName}"
                      value="#{sC.modComponent.component}"/>
        </ui:include>
    </div>
        <ace:contextMenu id="wdPopup">
            <c:forEach var="mItem" items="${menuBean.items}">
                <ace:menuItem action="#{menuBean.action}">
                </ace:menuItem>
            </c:forEach>
        </ace:contextMenu>
    </ui:fragment>
</f:facet>
```

It's not work, but it seems that all actions are invoked (on the client and server side), judging by the logs. 
But when i'm changin ace:dialog to ice:panelPopup it's get window to me. How can i fix that? I should use ace, not ice component.

Comment: Micheal Firstly i'll try using ui:repeat in place of c:forEach when using ace:dialog and here is the link which always helped me.http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=ace:dialog Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. This cycle should call a pop-up menu in the dialog box. But the problem is that the dialog box does not open. I think the problem is how I call it. Thanks for the link, everything from there I already tried. Here is a small piece of the button, with which I try to call a window. It goes through the code where JavaScriptRunner is used

Comment: <h:commandLink partialSubmit="true"
                             title="#{controller.description}"
                             actionListener="#{controller.actionPerformed}"
                             styleClass="toolbarButtonText"
                             immediate="#{controller.action.immediate}">
                <ace:ajax execute="@form"/>
</h:commandLink>